# Does time.tzname differ in winter vs summer if DST is used?

Tags: python

time.tzname on my system in summer is ("CET","CEST"). It is OK - there is summer time shift. But what will be the value in winter? The same or ("CET","CET") ?
In other words: does time.tzname[1] show "todays" time zone or constant "alternative" DST zone for my region?

Comment: It probably depends on the implementation of the `tzinfo` class. It's hard to make generalizations when there isn't a standard implementation that comes with Python.

Comment: thanks; and what about time.altzone ?